# JDeveloper error in first line of jsp "Name: expecting identifier"

Tags: jsp, compiler-errors, jdeveloper

I previously used JDeveloper 10g and now installed JDeveloper 12c and it marks many errors in JSP code where there had not been any errors previously.
An example code would be a simple, empty code block:

```
<%!
%>
```

The first char of the first line is marked as error, and the Live Issues window is reading

```
Error(1): Name: Expecting identifier.
```

[screenshot of code example and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr54o.png)

There is no additional help available and I have searched for but haven't found a solution. What does this mean, what have I done wrong and how do I fix this?
If I run the code on the integrated weblogic server it throws no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying that.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/357684

hope that could help you.

Comment: That is an 11 years old thread for a product "BI Beans" which i haven't head of and which I don't think I'm using. It also seems that there isn't any material for this "BI Beans" any more on the oracle pages.
The described error is different though.